# c# connecting to mysql on different server

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a c# web service running on a different webspace to my MySQL database. i want to link them together so have the following c# code.

```
            server = "www.***.com";
        database = "MyDataBase";
        uid = "admin";
        password = "Password";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
        database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
        catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

on the catch exception im getting the following error

"Access denied for user 'admin'@'cpc13-ches4-2-0-cust195.9-1.cable.virginmedia.com' (using password: YES)"

im only running it locally at the moment so i dont know if that is helping or hindering.

Comment: I suggest you remove your virgin media customer information...

Answer (score 2):

Check your MySQL user settings to make sure the `admin` account is allowed to log in from machines other than `localhost`.

You can verify which hosts users are allowed to connect from like this:

```
select user, host from mysql.user
```

if the `admin` user can only connect from localhost, then you'll either want to set up permissions for the new host you are connecting from or for all hosts using `%`.

You can see what permissions `admin` has on localhost like this:

```
show grants for 'admin'@'localhost'
```

Then you can copy/paste those grants changing the host part to grant the same permissions on another host.

Answer (score 0):

You have to grant access for admin @ cpc.......

Login to mysql and do the following:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'%'
->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Or first check with this command to see the priv first.

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'admin'@'localhost';
```

And try again...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your MySql server allows remote connections.
And maybe your connection string is just not the exact one. Check connection strings here: http://connectionstrings.com/mysql

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to go to:

`Security > Logins > Click your account > Properties > User Mappings`

And ensure you have the correct permissions

Answer (score 0):

- Download and install "MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver" at http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/3.51.html.
- Using IP addresses instead of www.***.com
- Require open port 3306 on server

  ```
          string MyConString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" +
                                "SERVER=112.***.**.***;" +
                                "DATABASE=dbname;" +
                                "UID=u_name;" +
                                "PASSWORD=u_pass;port=3306;" +
                                "OPTION=3";
          OdbcConnection MyConnection = new OdbcConnection(MyConString);
          MyConnection.Open();
  ```